# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) for PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select some items from table, but the problem is shown that "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)". The db system cannot select something from table. What can I do?

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <?php
 include ('opendb.php');
 ......
 echo "Date: " . date("Y/m/d") . "<br>";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(semail) AS av FROM `table` ")or die( 
 mysql_error());  
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or die("No rows returned by query"); 
echo "Daily Volume: ".$result;
  ...... ?>
```

Comment: can you include the code of opendb.php here

Comment: it's a permission problem, I think root@localhost need password

Comment: Try to log on to phpMyAdmin using the same credentials as specified in opendb.php, does that work?

Comment: well we kinda need to see opendb.php, but I am guessing its just a simple permission problem! you need to input a password.

Comment: Its a privilege problem. If you don't have privileges to access the database or the credentials supplied to the database.php doesn't match to mysql.

Comment: opendb.php: _italic_ **bold** `<?php
     // Stablish database connection
     include_once ('configdb.inc');
     $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die  ('Error connecting to mysql');
     //mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $conn);
     mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8", $conn);
     mysql_select_db($dbname);
     ?>`

Comment: what you have stored in $dbpass?

Comment: $dbpass is my db (phpmyadmin) password.

Comment: that i know, it is an phpmyadmin password. I am asking what is the value of $dbpass or what you are storing in it? and also have you set any password for phpmyadmin manually?

Comment: The value of $dbpass is stored on other file 'configdb.inc', which shows the user and passwoed inside the file. I also set the password for phpmyadmin, which is as same as the the password inside the file

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with your opendb.php file
make sure your database connections credentials are correct.
For some db the default password is root(LAMP environment)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you do not have any password associated to root so instead of 'NO' left the password equal to '' i.e. empty in your opendb.php !

Answer (score -1):

in opendb.php you might have used mysql_connect() function use like this. This will solve your problem

```
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("sorry not connected");
```